# why is the script not calculating all displayed bars?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am totally confused why the script only shows labels for last 30 bars? I want to get the high for every 10 bars back and display at the bar with the high (bar_index_high) the high value (highValue). I figured that only 30 bars are done by the script that's why the label is there as an indication where the script is doing something.  Can someone help me understand the problem? Thank you

```
//@version=5
indicator("Highestbars", overlay = true)
plot (bar_index, color = color.maroon)

// find the latest high
var bar_index_high = bar_index
var highValue = high

label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(bar_index) + ":" + str.tostring(high), textcolor = color.white)

for i = 1 to 10
    if high[i] > highValue
        bar_index_high := bar_index[i]
        highValue := high[i]

if (bar_index_high > 0)
    label.new(bar_index_high, high, "!" + str.tostring(highValue), textcolor = color.white)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
indicator("Highestbars", overlay = true, max_labels_count = 500 )
```

Comment: thank you. oh man. I only looked at max_bars_back and wondered why there was no change.